# convert `web::json::object` to `web::json::value`

Tags: c++, json

Do you know a way to convert 
`web::json::object` to `web::json::value` ?

I have tried `web::json::value::object(anObject)` but it doesn't accept `web::json::object`

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a simple json example:

```
{ num = "221", address = "Baker street" }
```

That is a json::object. To convert an object into a value, use at, or []:

```
// obj = { num = "221", address = "Baker street" }
web::json::value obj;
obj.add("num", "221");
obj.add("address", "Baker street");
std::cout << obj.type() << std::endl; // Should give 3 for object
web::json::value num1 = obj["num"];
web::json::value num2 = obj.at("num");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
web::json::object jo; //Your object
web::json::value jv = web::json::value::object(std::vector<std::pair<::utility::string_t, web::json::value>>jo.begin(), jo.end()), false);
```